# Stuck in GRUB rescue mode showing error 'symbol 'term_box_disabled' not found'

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

I get the error of

```
 error : symbol 'term_box_disabled' not found
```

when I try to boot Oracle Solaris from my USB drive, I have also selected the right partition by typing

```
set prefix=(hd0,mdos1)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,mdos1)
insmod normal
normal
```

but it still gives me the error I mention. Who knows how to solve it?

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/etc/grub/default`?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix how i go there if i cant even enter LINUX, it show me this error when i trying to dual boot it